# compare two excel files and write matches and non matches to third in ruby

Tags: excel, ruby, xlsx, xls

I want to compare two xlsx files and write to a third.

Sheet1 has `url` and `id` fields and Sheet2 has `url` and `type` fields. If there is a url match, combine the data and write to sheet3, which will have `url`, `id`, and `type`. Crucially, I want to preserve all non matching urls from sheet1 and include them in sheet3. In essence this means that some rows will have a nil `type` value.

Is there a way to accomplish this without sloppily including all non matches and rapidly exceeding the Excel row limit?

My code only catches matching urls:

```
require 'simple_xlsx_reader'
require 'write_xlsx'

sheet3 = WriteXLSX.new('sheet3.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet
col = 0
row = 0
worksheet.write(0, 0, "ID")
worksheet.write(0, 1, "URL")
worksheet.write(0, 2, "Type")

sheet1 = SimpleXlsxReader.open("sheet1.xlsx")
sheet2 = SimpleXlsxReader.open("sheet2.xlsx")

sheet1.sheets.first.rows.each(headers: true) do |p|
 sheet2.sheets.first.rows.each(headers: true) do |c|
  if p["URL"] == c["URL"]
   row = row + 1 #this is here because 'each_with_index' does not work with simple_xlsx_reader
   worksheet.write(row, 0, p["ID"])
   worksheet.write(row, 1, p["URL"])
   worksheet.write(row, 2, c["Type"])
  else
   #this is my problem section. any else condition here catches every single non match on every single iteration, and the row limit is exceeded.
  end
 end
end

sheet1.close
```

How can I catch the non matching urls?

Comment: This is where a look-up table or using `Set` for intersections can be very handy.

Comment: thank you! looking into this. are you sure that `Set` is what I need? i want to catch matches and then keep everything in sheet1 that has no match, because the `type` field will be decided manually at a later date

Comment: A good place to start is [`group_by`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/enumerable#method-i-group_by) or with [`index_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by) if using Rails. These give you a way to quickly look-up matches by things like URL, no more linear scans. Then you can trivially pull in data, even using `lookup.dig(p["URL"], 0, "type")` for example.

Comment: You may want to split this up a little to make it easier to understand and test. For example, make a function that performs the "sheet" to array of rows transformation, then another that can add rows to another worksheet. In Ruby it's often the case you'll want to make a simple class to encapsulate this, so it could be as easy as `target << { id: ..., url: .., type: ... }` in practice by implementing `def <<(row)`. Your internal `@row` index is then no longer something this code needs to pay attention to.